# where can i find hibernateProperties?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

i have not placed any hibernate.properties in the classpath so then why its not throwing any exception for ${test} for key hibernate.show_sql, if the key is not found.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
         <property name="mappingLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:test.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property> 
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${test}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Do you have configured a ProprtyPlaceholderConfigurer?

Comment: not configured ProprtyPlaceholderConfigurer